# Nexus 5 / Android 4.4 - web apps do not work as web apps

Tags: android, html, web-applications

I cannot add a web app to the home screen on the nexus 5, android 4.4

I've followed the instructions found at this link
https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/installtohomescreen

You can test the problem with this app for example:
http://weight.aerotwist.com

After following the instructions, I get an homescreen icon, but tapping on it brings up a menu with the various browsers available instead of just opening the web app.

I've tested the same problem with a locally installed app and it gives the message "App isn't installed".

It looks like a bug. Can anyone confirm this? Does anyone know a workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The cause of this problem is that in Android 4.4, `WebView` was changed as in previously it was based on Webkit browser, and now its based on Chromium browser.

You can follow [this guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html) to help migrating your app to Android 4.4

Comment: Hello thanks for the fast reply.

I'm not developing a Webview web-app.

I'm working on an html5 web-app that I want to add to the home screen, as explained in the link from developers.google.com